# Color wash out problem when I connect my laptop to a projector or LCD monitor

Tags: color, color-profile

I have a critical problem when i connect my laptop to a projector. Colors that I have used in my website are getting washed out when it's displayed on the projector screen.

Comment: Maybe someone has tinkered with the projector settings..? You might want to try to reset them. Or.. maybe check out Brightness settings in the projector? ( of course you might want to try lights off if you aren't doing it like that already. :) )

Comment: Can you include a link to the site?

Comment: Definitely mess with the projector settings. I have yet to find one that actually handles colors well, you are most likely out of luck and have to accept that it's gonna look bad.

Comment: Most projectors are crappy. It's a hardware issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal behavior for projector vs. screen. They are not the same, just as screen vs. print is not the same. You may have to do a mockup of your website in Photoshop with different colors and experiment with the projector so that the end result looks like what your website is supposed to be.

Comment: And having the correction as an adjustment layer would be good — it'd mean you can turn it off and on at will, apply it quickly to many documents and export with it on for the final images to be projected.

Answer (score 0):

Does it look okay if you connect it to another projector / LCD screen? If so, it may be that there's an issue with the projector (if it's an older one there may be burn-in or it may be that the LCD unit is dying and showing wash-out). Check the cable - if you have a broken pair you may not be getting all of the R, G, or B information. If you can verify it's not the cable by just swapping the cable out.

If it looks washed out on another screen / projector, it may be the output port settings on your laptop. Without knowing the type and age of your laptop I can't make any definitive statements but you could try swapping your primary and secondary displays to see if it's an issue with the way stuff is being displayed out of that port.

Answer (score 0):

This PDF will help you. Change the color setting in your displays. You'll understand what I mean when you read this.

http://www.fdi.vt.edu/news/Macintosh_Video_Projector_Fix.pdf

Comment: Hey stephanie! As Dominic said, link-only answers don't work out because we cannot depend on their longevity. You can instead flesh out your answer to reference parts of what you linked, or I could convert your answer to a comment if you'd rather that.

Comment: The linked page is down now, because the site has reorganized itself. The page is not in [Google’s cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fdi.vt.edu%2Fnews%2FMacintosh_Video_Projector_Fix.pdf) or the [Wayback Machine](http://archive.org/web/web.php).